# Table is marked as crashed and should be repaired where condition is not supported

Tags: mysql, sql, crash

I am facing the problem where the table is okay but whenever I want to add a condition in the query it is showing that the table is marked as crashed and should be repaired error in the console.

```
Select * from transaction where transactionOid = '100/102022/1039';
```

The transaction table is working fine without the where condition. Looking forward to the solutions.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW CREATE TABLE transaction; and B) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE 'transaction';  for analysis.